# Linking embeddable one widget to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a couple of widgets that are embeddable for any website. So, users who want to use those widgets will get a script bundle and couple of divs.

I want to link one widget to another. Assume, there are four widgets used on a website. I want to link them as users will click on one widget it will scroll to another.

Is there any way to connect one widget to another?

> Suppose,  there is one widget click here to know the details. If a user clicks on that will scroll to the details section which is another widget embedded with just a div.

> This is what my goal is. Thanks

Comment: If **all** you need to do is scroll to that widget (and each widget shouldn't appear more than once per page) then simply using a static ID at the top level of each widget would let you scroll between them.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:-

Suppose this is your details widget:-

```
<div id="details-widget">  
details-widget  
</div>
```

You can scroll down to above div by writing the 'click here widget' in the following way: -

```
<div>  
   <a href="#details-widget">click here</a>
</div>
```

Basically, you have to mention the id of the div in href of 'a' tag. On clicking the 'click here', it will scroll down to 'details widget'.